# Find the size of the maximum cycle in a MPS

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, distributed-systems

Consider the following problem to be solved in a distributed context:

> Find for each processor the size of the biggest cycle of which it is member.

My algorithm is the following (for synchronous MPS):

```
procedure findMaxCycleSize
cycle_size := 0
send(my_id, 1) to all my neighbors
for i:=1 to n do
    receive(id, size)
    if id = my_id then
        if size > cycle_size then
            cycle_size := size
        end if
    else
        send to all my neighbors except sender (id, size+1)
    end if
done
```

**Analisys**

$n+1$ rounds are enough, in fact a cycle can have size at most $n$, so the time complexity is **$\Theta(n)$**

Message complexity is very high, $O(n*n^n)$, this because every processor is responsible of at most $n^n$ message.
The best case is when every processor has degree exactly $2$ (ring topology) and we would have $O(n^2)$ messages.

The problem is that this algorithm is wrong, suppose the following case,
[image]

it will return for $p_1$ 5 but this is not true.

**improvement #1**
The first message has another field "destination node", so the processor can check if the message comes from the processor to which he initially forwarded the message

```
procedure findMaxCycleSize
cycle_size := 0
send(my_id, v, 1) to all v neighbors
for i:=1 to n do
    receive(id,v, size)
    if id = my_id then
        if sender_id is not v and size > cycle_size then
            cycle_size := size
        end if
    else
        send to all my neighbors except sender (id,v, size+1)
    end if
done
```

I have 2 questions:

- Is my analisys correct?
- How can I fix the algorithm to improve message complexity?

Comment: Is the graph undirected? And what assumptions do we have on the memory of each precessor (ist it linear/sublinear in the number of nldes)?